# Browser Cache over Sub-Domain/Domain

Tags: javascript, css, caching, resources

I have a question - I am hosting my files on a static sub-domain

```
http://subdomain.domain.com
http://www.domain.com
```

Currently, resources on the subdomain are ONLY accessible via HTTP [not https://]. For now, I request https:// resources via www.domain.com

Will resources requested from subdomain.domain.com be "cached" for https://. That is, lets say user comes to "home" and requests

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/style.css
```

Will this resource be used on

```
https://www.domain.com/style.css
```

or is this considered a new request ? i.e. its not cached from subdomain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that to be considered a new request and not taken from cache (and indeed, if you tried to use the version cached from the non-secured page, the browser would consider that a mix of secure and insecure content).

Comment: yeah thats my prob :( the static hosting doesn't allow HTTPS at this time. so does this mean its 2x resources just for HTTPS ? ps - i am using azure btw.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so, unless you have a way to proxy the resource request through the secured site (which may eliminate the gains from hosting your resources statically anyway).

Comment: For what it's worth, here's an article about using HTTPS with Azure:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/12/01/how-to-add-an-https-endpoint-to-a-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx